# sudo pecl install sqlsrv ERROR: failed to mkdir /usr/local/Cellar/php/7.4.1/pecl/20190902 on Catalina php7.4

Tags: php, macos-catalina, sqlsrv

I am trying to install sqlsrv on the new mac Catalina and keep getting the same error:

> Build process completed successfully
>
> Installing '/usr/local/Cellar/php/7.4.1/pecl/20190902/sqlsrv.so'
>
> ERROR: failed to mkdir /usr/local/Cellar/php/7.4.1/pecl/20190902

I'm not sure what's the problem is... please help.

Comment: i believe they updated for Catalina.  i no longer get this error.

Answer (score 5):

The pecl part of the path: /usr/local/Cellar/php/7.4.1/**pecl**/20190902 is a symlink to /usr/local/lib/php/**pecl** which might not exist in your system.

Thus the error.

The quick fix would be to:

```
 mkdir -p /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20190902
```